# Include SSRS report image into SSIS send mail task

Tags: email, url, reporting-services, ssis, send

I have SSRS reports that are attainable from url.

I would like to include this report into SSIS's Send mail task body. Actually I simply put the link of a report into mail's body and clicking on it I can access to the report. But I would like to see that report directly into email body like an image/snapshot of the report.

Is it possible? 
Thanks

Comment: This sort of thing is natively available with SSRS subscriptions. Have you considered using these?

Comment: Hi Ian, can you explain better what do you mean?